# How to approach similar triangles problems?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

How to solve similar triangle problems? I have no idea how to identify corresponding pairs and make proportions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\Delta LWY$ and $\Delta LYA$ are both right triangle and share LY and angle $\angle L$ thus $\Delta LWY\sim\Delta LYA$ and

$$\frac{\text{hypotenuse}}{\text{short side}}=\frac{LY}{AL}=\frac{LW}{LY}$$

Comment: How do use select corresponding sides? I'm confused with finding corresponding pairs

Comment: Both triangles are right, you choose hypotenuse/short-side ratio

Answer (score 1):

Two triangles are similar if and only if they have the same angles. The corresponding pairs of sides are made by the sides which are opposite to congruent angles. This is the way to identify pairs of sides which are directly proportional.

Comment: I have learned the whole concept, but in this example I don't know why its quite challenging to identify the corresponding pairs. Maybe the pairs are not in correct order or the smaller triangle has been rotated around a point.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\Delta LWY\sim\Delta LYA,$ we obtain
$$\frac{LW}{LY}=\frac{LY}{LA}$$ or
$$\frac{LW}{\sqrt{3.5^2+7.0^2}}=\frac{\sqrt{3.5^2+7.0^2}}{3.5}$$ or
$$LW=17.5.$$

Comment: How do you figure out which side corresponds to which side?

Comment: Because $LW$ opposite to $\angle Y$, in $\Delta LWY$ and $LY$ opposite  to $\angle A$ in $\Delta LYA$ and these angles they are equal. The rest is the same.

Comment: Can you please simplify your explanation? Why do you take LW as comparison? What shall I be looking for when solving similar problems?

Comment: By definition $\Delta ABC\sim\Delta PQR$ iff $\angle A=\angle P$, $\angle B=\angle Q$, $\angle C=\angle R$, and $\frac{AB}{PQ}=\frac{AC}{PR}=\frac{BC}{QR}.$

Answer (score 0):

we get two equations
$$l^2=x^2+7.0^2$$ ($l=YW$)
$$l^2+LY^2=(3.5+x)^2$$ and ($$LY=\sqrt{3.5^3+7.0^2}$$)